# Error in read_fun(path = path, sheet = sheet, limits = limits, shim = shim

Tags: r, xls, readxl

I am trying to read xls file using `read_excel` function of readxl package in R. But it is showing error as

> Error in read_fun(path = path, sheet = sheet, limits = limits, shim =
>   shim).

I tried with other xls file, it is working but not with my original file. My file has multiple sheets. I tried all packages xlconnect, readxl, xlsx, tidyverse, gdata but nothing helped.

I tried on my friend's system who have win 7, there it is working fine. I have win 10 system.

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible, which makes it hard to troubleshoot (& may get closed for this reason). Since the issue occurs with a specific file, you may want to check further what actually triggers it. Does the problem occur if you make a copy of the file with a single sheet? Is there a specific sheet / column / cell that triggers it?

Comment: No..If I am reading file with only one sheet, then it works fine. With multiple sheets I can read the same file on win 7 system but not on win 10.